# lodash sortby, how to sort numbers later than letters?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have a list with both numbers and strings in there.

Each element of the list looks something like:

```
{
  'name': 'Bob',
  'number': 234234
}
```

But, either name or number may be missing.

In my sortBy I did something like this:

```
_.sortBy(list, function(element) {
  if (element.name) {
    return element.name;
  }
  else {
    return element.number;
  }
});
```

This sorts the elements with numbers in front of the elements without it. How do I get lodash to deprioritize numbers?

Comment: Would you be willing to use a native JavaScript solution, or do you want to stick with lodash?

Comment: I figured out a native JS solution using the .sort() function, but it ended up being much much longer than a sortBy solution would have been. I'm ok keeping it this way for now, but if someone has a better idea I'd appreciate that too.

Comment: What's your intended output here?  All entires with names, sorted by name, followed by all entries with number, sorted by number?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you mean is simply that _.sortBy ranks in *ascending order*?

> sortBy_.sortBy(list, iteratee, [context])  Returns a (stably) sorted
>   copy of list, ranked in ascending order by the results of running each
>   value through iteratee. iteratee may also be the string name of the
>   property to sort by (eg. length).

http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy

Therefore, as you are prioritizing `element.name`, it appears last on the sort.

You can simply reverse the resulting array

```
results = results.reverse();
```

Or, change the order of your `if/else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

`_.sortBy` is using the return value to create an object with a `criteria` property. That `criteria` property is the value to compare with the `array.sort` function and an `ad hoc`, not configurable `comparer` function.

I guess you can hack this, returning a value like:

```
    _.sortBy(list, function(element) {
      if (element.name) {
        return "@" + element.name;
      }
      else {
        return element.number;
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it might be easier to split the list, sort the parts and put it back together, i.e.:

```
 _(data) //begin chain
    .filter("name") //the entries with names
    .sortBy("name") //sorted by name
    .concat(_.sortBy(_.reject(data, "name"), "number")) //followed by the entries without name, sorted by number
    .value(); //end chain
```